Cell structure on the function space $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$
By the Theorem of Milnor in his paper  "On spaces having the homotopy type of a CW-complex", the function space $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ (with the compact-open topology) is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex (say $Z$) when $X$ is compact.
Do we know anything about the cell structure (of $Z$) in this case?
[When $X$ is $S^n$, I believe there is a well-known construction, and I would like to know more about it as well.]

These mapping spaces do not admit CW structures. They are (when $X$ is compact) homotopy equivalent to CW complexes.

Oh yes, I meant that I would like to know the cell structure of the space $Z$ that is homotopy equivalent to $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ when $X$ is compact (also when it is the $n$-sphere). Thanks for the clarification! :)

I have edited my question. ^^

You can make a simplicial set of the right homotopy type by letting the $n$-simplices be the maps $\Delta^n\times X \to Y$.

Related question https://mathoverflow.net/q/309542 There is a well known construction when $X=S^n$ and $Y=S^n Z$, with $Z$ connected. The construction generalises to the case when $X$ is a parallellisable n-dimensional manifold.

@GregoryArone, thanks for the link; is there any other references for it though?

Check the paper of Clement Berger, linked in that answer. It gives a survey, and further references.

@GregoryArone: the answer is now gone (I guess deleted, hence only visible to users with 10K+ rep.). Could you kindly post the link the comments?

@M.G. I mean the answer to the question that I linked to  in the first comment. That answer is very much present. Anyhow, here is the link https://math.univ-cotedazur.fr/~cberger/cell.pdf

@GregoryArone: oh, sorry, I misunderstood. I thought I noticed the question getting answered, but the answer then getting deleted. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for posting the link!

@ GregoryArone : Thanks. I found several references from your answer/link. They were very helpful, thank you! :)

@ Dave Benson : How do we construct such a simplicial set?
